# Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: magento2.4.3

Getting below error when creating an invoice
"Server cannot understand Content-Type HTTP header media type application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when we use application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Spring doesn't understand it as a RequestBody. So, if we want to use this we must remove the @RequestBody annotation.

Then try the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patientdetails", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody List<PatientProfileDto> getPatientDetails(
        PatientProfileDto name) {


    List<PatientProfileDto> list = new ArrayList<PatientProfileDto>();
    list = service.getPatient(name);
    return list;
}
```

Note that removed the annotation @RequestBody